# How to enable F# Interactive in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Issue: No F# Interactive window.

Background: I had F# Interactive working just fine then apparently did something that has made it disappear, and it's not showing when hitting Alt-Enter with code selected.

Expected Result: I thought Alt + Enter opened the FSI window with code selected but it's not happening.

EDIT: Somehow it's back. I now have F# Interactive as an option in the Terminal dropdown where as before it only had Powershell. Wierd but working...

Comment: Isn't the interactive window a **visual Studio** and not a **visual studio code** feature?

Comment: No, it's also in VS Code.

Answer (score 10):

Open the Command Palette with `Ctrl+Shift+P` and find `FSI: Start` command (requires Ionide extension)

[image]

Comment: Anyone know how to specify a startup .fsx script, like in Visual Studio proper?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/get-started-vscode#configure-f-interactive) you can also do the following:

1. Open the Visual Studio Code settings (File > Preferences >
   Settings).
2. Search for the term F# Script.
3. Click the checkbox that says FSharp: use SDK scripts.

Now you can highlight a line of code (like `let foo = 1`) and send it to `F# Interactive` by using `Alt + Enter`. It should now open the terminal in `F# Interactive` mode.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you pressed `Ctrl + F` and while the search dialog was open, the `Alt + Enter` key combo failed...